# Running a simulation multiple times and calculating an average

Tags: python, loops, simulation

I've created a simulation of particles, the function run takes in the no. of particles and their halft lives and then the time to run it and the number of steps:

```
def run(A, B, C, t1, t2, t3, time, steps):
    dt = time/steps
    
    p_A = 1/t1 * dt
    p_B = 1/t2 * dt
    p_C = 1/t3 * dt

    testrules_N = [
        ('A', 'B', p_A),
        ('B', 'C', p_B),
        ('C', 'A', p_C)
    ]

    testrules = [
        ('A', 'B', p_A),
        ('B', 'C', p_B)
    ]
    A1,B1,C1 = evolve_system(A, B, C, testrules_N, steps)
    A2,B2,C2 = evolve_system(A1[-1], B1[-1], C1[-1], testrules, steps)
    return A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to run it 20 times and then for each step average all the values over the 20 similations to created an average simulation with an error at each point

What I have so far is:

```
A1, B1, C1 = A0, B0, C0

populations = numpy.zeros((20, 10 * (nsim + 1))) 

values = run(A0, B0, C0, t_half_A, t_half_B, t_half_C, t_total, nsteps)

for i in range(0, nsim):
    populations[i + 1] = values [i]
    numpy.average(populations)[i]
    numpy.std(populations)[i]
```

I know this is nothing close to what is need but can anyone help me on this?

Comment: If `run` runs your simulation, use a loop to call it the desired number of times and accumulate statistics on the return values. I’m failing to see what the difficulty is here. Note: you haven’t shared code that we can test, since your program calls a function `evolve_system()` which you haven’t provided.

Comment: Thanks for the help, managed to get it sorted in the end, as you send wasn't too bad